# How to use $.ajax() to Upload Files

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I get this message when I try to use $_FILES to get the image name.

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: image in **C:\xampp\htdocs\upload_form\upload_query.php** on line **10**

I have a form that uploads information about an image to a mysql database (phpmyadmin), and then the form is cleared using JavaScript so that the user can upload another image and information.
I have read that you can't use $_FILES as well as JavaScript, but I am unsure why, I would also appreciate a solution.

I am new to php, and JavaScript.

This is the JavaScript.

```
$('form').on('submit',function() {
var that= $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value) {
           var that = $(this),
           name = that.attr('name'),
           value = that.val();

           data[name] = value;
    });

 $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: type, 
         data: data,
         success: function(response){
                  console.log(response);
         }
 });
  document.getElementById("upload_form").reset();
return false;
});
```

This is the php.

```
 //image properties
 $name   = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $size   = $_FILES['image']['size'];
 $temp   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 $error  = $_FILES['image']['error'];
 $type   = $_FILES['image']['type'];
 //****************
```

This is part of the form.

```
<form action='upload_query.php' class='appnitro' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='upload_form' method='post' name='upload_form'>
  <ul>
    <li id='li_1'>
      <label class='description' for='image'>Upload a Picture</label>    
      <div>
        <input class='element file' id='image' name='image' required="" type='file'>
      </div>
    </li>    
    <li id='li_2'><label class='description' for='name'>Name</label> <span><input class='element text' id='first_name' maxlength='255' name='first_name' placeholder='First Name.' required="" size='12' value=''></span> <span><input class='element text' id='last_name' maxlength='255' name='last_name' placeholder='Last Name.' required="" size='18' value=''></span></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

etc.

Comment: even that can send files check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

---

Yes you can upload files using `$.ajax` here is how

First let's have a typical form with an id. This form can include your one or many files as you wish.

```
<form id='fileupload' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" ...
```

Then in jQuery you do the following.

```
$('#btnupload').click(function () {
    //the key is FormData object
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('fileupload'));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php', //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (json) {}
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

The key here is using the javascript [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to construct the data parameter of `$.ajax`

Comment: Thanks Fabricio, i don't know how to do that indent yet

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why not just use `$('#fileupload')[0]` instead of `document.getElementById`? The only effective difference I see is if the `fileupload` form doesn't exist (in which case the jQuery way returns `undefined`, while `getElementById` returns `null`, but I don't think that makes a difference with `FormData`'s constructor).

Comment: Not criticizing(answer is good). But now i know why i didn't used it because Formdata is not supported in many major browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: FormData is supported in all browsers other than IE9 and older.

Comment: @RayNicholus don't tell me that you don't take care of IE developing your project

Comment: @Ankit Of course I do.  Never said I didn't.  For browsers that do not support the File API, Fine Uploader utilizes forms that target hidden iframes to upload files.  There's no sense in not using FormData just because it isn't supported in all browsers.  Most browsers have proper file API support.  For those that don't you use iframes.

Comment: @DevZer0 +1 In addition to use of `FormData`, the other important key that makes your answer work is the false value on the `processData` option.  If this is not set to false, jQuery will attempt to turn the `FormData` into a URL-encoded query string.  Many people who try to upload files via jQuery run into problems because they don't realize that `processData` must be set to false.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot send files using AJAX (not this way).

If you want to send files, take a look at XMLHttpRequest2.
Pretty good tutorial is here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: you can send files using ajax

Comment: @DevZer0 are you crazy? Take a look at that answer before downvoting without reason

Comment: Answer is not exactly good, but the tutorial deserves a +1 (to compensate that downvote).